A manhwa/manga about a guy sending himself into another world
He doesn’t like living on Earth so he spent his life trying to find a way to another world.
He managed to find a way to send himself, but he meets some gods and one of them said that the new reincarnation law it but because he was the first person to do it in a long time they sent him to another world but without his memory.
He unlocked a skill that lets him regain it.

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

It was in full colour.
